# Fail to Inject ComponentFactoryResolver

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to use ComponentFactoryResolver to create dynamic angular component. The below is my code to inject ComponentFactoryResolver.

```
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app-component",
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    `
})
export default class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private title = "Hello World";


    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){

    }

    ngOnInit() {}


}
```

It throw the below exception in browser console.

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
```

The used dependency (package.json). I use webpack to compile js and include js in HTML for run.

```
{
  "name": "angular_hello_world_example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --colors --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

Additional Information for Module Declaration

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import AppComponent from './AppComponent';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
export default class AppModule {


}
```

Comment: could it be `onClick()` . its not present in your code but you are using it in your template.

Comment: Thanks. I pasted outdated code. it does not work too for the updated code.

Comment: I think the dynamic component that you have made needs to be listed in `app.module.ts` in entry components. have you done that?

Comment: I just inject ComponentFactoryResolver which does not work.

Comment: There is no common explanation for the thing you're describing. It should work http://plnkr.co/edit/cHMfI2NAexnVbVLkPPu9?p=preview . It could be wrong TS configuration, which isn't covered in the question. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue.

Comment: Yes. I finally found the root cause. It is due to incorrect ts config. Missing "emitDecoratorMetadata": true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @estus. It is due to incorrect ts config. emitDecoratorMetadata is missing in tsconfig.json.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "target",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```